# Casting between uint8_t * and char *. What happens?

Tags: objective-c, c, string, casting

What happens when casting between these two in relation to the termination character? In C99 Objective-C.

Comment: The only thing a cast does is get rid of compiler warnings, unless you cast a floating point to an integer, or vice versa. The output code is exactly the same.

Comment: This is not true. The C language *does not define* any implicit conversion between different pointer types (aside from `void *` of course). A cast is *the only way* to convert. A compiler that allows conversion without a cast and only generates a warning is being misguidedly "generous" to you; it's not correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that a char is 8 bits on your system in this answer.

If your architecture uses `unsigned char` as `char` type then absolutely nothing will happen.

If your architecture uses `signed char` as `char` type then negative values of char will wrap around causing possibly unexpected results. This however will never happen to the termination null character.

---

Please note, by "casting" nothing really happens, you just tell the compiler to interpret a certain location in the memory differently. This difference in interpretation would create the actual (side)effects of the cast.

Comment: Thank you but I thought some types were converted specially. For example float to int. It has to be converted. But for pointers, nothing ever happens to the data with any cast?

Comment: casting a float to int value will convert the value on copy. Casting a pointer to a block of ints to floats will just leave you with weird values in the floats - nothign is changed

Comment: Of-course, yes. Didn't know if there were exceptions. I found a website somewhere which was saying the wrong thing about uint8_t and char which confused me so I had to come here.

Comment: @Matthew Mitchell: Which website?

Comment: If `char` is not 8-bit, `uint8_t` **cannot exist** and there's no question.

Comment: So char must be an uint8_t if uint8_t is defined?

Answer (score 0):

If `char` and `uint8_t` are compatible types (they should be on most current desktop computers), pointers to objects of that type have the same representation and alignment requirements, so there should be no problem converting (implicitly, or explicitly with a cast) one to the other.

The values pointed to, again, if they are compatible, should be treated equally no matter what type they are interpreted as.

*Note: I am not 100% certain that `uint8_t` and `char` are compatible on a implementation with signed chars.*

If the types are not compatible you invoke Undefined Behaviour and anything can happen: a very likely thing to happen is that everything "works" as you expect -- **but there is no guarantee it will always work the same**

Comment: Regardless of compatibility, you have not invoked UB. **Any type** can be accessed as an overlaid array of `unsigned char [sizeof(type)]`.

Comment: Hmmm ... of course! I was just picturing `uint8_t` as incompatible with `char`, but I can't imagine `uint8_t` existing and be incompatible with `char`.

Comment: I don't think they're considered "compatible" unless `char` happens to be unsigned; it's just that `unsigned char` is special and can access anything. Actually, technically I suppose `uint8_t` could be an "extended integer type" with the same properties as `unsigned char` except for aliasing properties, in which case the code might invoke UB....